# splitting a bezier curve in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, path, split, bezier

I would like to "grow" a path with bezier-curves. After the path has been drawn, it should be shaking a bit: Weave-like look and feel.
visual example:
[weave example](http://www.ceylor.ch/#/wiki/)
At the moment I use TweenMax.bezier, which let me move a point along this curve and at the same time (onEnterFrame) I draw lines to the current Position of the Point.
Unfortunately this approach leads to bad quality of the curve if the framerate drops(square-cut) and it is difficult to recalculate all the points in between(for the weave effect);
Recent suggestions lead me to use curves to solve the problem, but I don't know exactly how.
This example would solve my problem: [split bezier](http://lab.andre-michelle.com/split-bezier)
But no code-snippets.

Did anyone encounter the same problem ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use **Tweeners** `CurveModifiers._bezier_get` to create bezier curves and retrieve points easily (I've tried a few and this one is actually fast).

**... Quickly :**

Set up two arrays (x,y) listing the control points.

Iterate each frame to modify the positions of the control points.

Redraw your curve with some similar code :

```
for(var i:Number=0; i <1; i += precision)
{ 
   x = CurveModifiers._bezier_get(pathX[0], pathX[pathX.length - 1], t, pathX);
   y = CurveModifiers._bezier_get(pathY[0], pathY[pathY.length - 1], t, pathY);
   // ...graphics.lineTo(x,y)
}
```

**Edit**

Here you go :

```
import caurina.transitions.*;
import caurina.transitions.properties.CurveModifiers;


addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event) 
{   
    modifyCurve();
    drawCurve();
}

// Control points

var pathX:Array = new Array(50,200,600,850);
var pathY:Array = new Array(50,200,100,350);


// growth related

var growth:Number=0;
var growthSpeed:Number=0.01;


/**
* Grows and draws the curve
*/
function drawCurve():void {

    const precision:Number = 0.001;

    var cx:Number,
        cy:Number;

    // grow (avoid making it more than one)

    if (growth<1) growth = Math.min(1, growth+growthSpeed);

    graphics.clear();
    graphics.lineStyle(1);

    for (var t:Number=0; t <growth; t += precision) {

        cx=CurveModifiers._bezier_get(pathX[0],pathX[pathX.length-1],t,pathX);
        cy=CurveModifiers._bezier_get(pathY[0],pathY[pathY.length-1],t,pathY);

        if (t==0) {
            graphics.moveTo(cx,cy);
        } else {
            graphics.lineTo(cx,cy);
        }
    }
}


var motion_t:Number = 0;
var motionSpeed:Number = Math.PI * 0.1;
var motionRadius:Number = 10*motionSpeed;


/**
* Creates a movement by transforming the control points
*/
function modifyCurve():void
{
    var len:int = pathX.length;

    motion_t += motionSpeed;

    for(var index:int = 1; index < len; index++)
    {
        // simple circular movement for each control point

        pathX[index] += Math.cos(motion_t + Math.PI * 2 / index) * motionRadius;
        pathY[index] += Math.sin(motion_t + Math.PI * 2 / index) * motionRadius;

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,
but does this also allow "growing" the path along the bezier curve ?
Or do you have ideas how to implement this behavior?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, 0 represents the start and 1 the end so all you have to do is incrementing the end point each frame (starting at 0.001) until you reach 1. In the example above the end point is 1 obviously.

Comment: Oh sorry, re-read your question, missed the point with 'growing'. I'm obviously only talking about growing one branch... Thought you already had the logic setup and just looking for a way to draw nice bezier curves. sorry for that.

Comment: Ha just found something I did back in 2004, http://ttillberg.free.fr it uses sine/cosine only. Are you looking for something similar ?

Comment: Jeah, just my one does not split into new branches and has just limited growing (about 700px). Afterwards, if finished growing, it should start swinging like the example link I attached above.

Comment: Cool, then go for the first comment. Are you having trouble with understanding bezier curves in general ?

Comment: Just another question: Could your approach also be done without recalculating each point ?  I would like to "grow" more then one path. In this case the recalculation needs a lot of ressources(5 paths leads to a drop in the framerate to 20 instead of 30). 
I thought of something like this:
http://philippe.elsass.me/2009/06/as3-parametric-path-drawing/
but his example does not "grow" the paths but his "movement" of the paths doesn't need that much performance.
Should I start a new question for this ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Quickly, I Hope you've changed the precision, the default one from the example is extremely high.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is more commonly called the deCastlejau algorithm.  Blossoming or polar labels are more general methods for the same thing.